# How to validate the active directory domain my app is running in?

Tags: vb.net, security, active-directory

I have a VB.Net Application that authenticates using the current Windows User without asking for the password. It checks that this user is a member of "MYDOMAIN\ApplicationUsers" before it starts up.

How to check if this is the real domain and not a different one using the same name? Are there any certs or public keys to validate locally? I'd prefer to check this offline, without a third party machine or database etc.

In the System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory Namespace are some Trust an Validate methods but they only seem to check inter domain trust and using a domain name only.

Comment: How are you checking that the current user is a member of this group now? If you are using AD queries you may be able to use the current users SID and verify they are a member of the group.

Comment: I am using the Method [IsInRole(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.user.isinrole(v=vs.80).aspx) on the My.Application.User Object, using the string parameter given in my question. By using a string with the name of the domain this is "easily" forged by creating a rogue domain. Checking the SID is interesting, they are no real hash or cert but if there is nothing secure so be it.

Comment: It sounds like a chicken/egg problem. There are .net functions to validate that the user is who they say they are, but that usually involves asking them for a passwords. If you dont want to prompt them then you have to take their word (in this case DOMAIN). Is this application meant to be portable or within one organization? If its within one organization, you could use other clues to sniff out a dishonest user.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are using strings and strings like mydomain/application users are not unique across domains.  One possibility is to use the SID of the application users group in your expected domain instead of the name.  Then you can check the SID of the group to make sure it matches the sid for the expected application users group at run time  before checking membership.  It would be much harder for a malicious user to spoof domain and group parts of the Sid then the domain and group name.

Ultimately if you are running code on a machine that is owned by the malicious user then this just raises the bar and they could still circumvent this check.

Answer (score 1):

I made some example code which checks the group's SID as Mike suggested. You just need to put your group's SID in the constructor of the `SecurityIdentifier` class to make the check work against the currently logged on user.

```vb
Private Sub DoCheck()
    Dim sid As New Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier("S-0-0-00-0000000000-0000000000-0000000000-000"),
        result As Boolean
    result = IsUserInGroup(sid)
End Sub

Public Shared Function IsUserInGroup(sid As Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier) As Boolean
    Dim user As UserPrincipal
    user = UserPrincipal.Current
    For Each group As Principal In user.GetGroups()
        If group.Sid.Equals(sid) Then Return True
    Next
    Return False
End Function
```

To make the code work you need to import `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`:

```vb
Imports System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
```

This namespace is located in Microsoft's `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.dll` which is available since .Net 4.0 I believe.